# UIAlertController and displayShareSheet crashing on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, uibutton

I have a UIButton within a view.  The UIButton is positioned like

[image]

I have an @IBAction that is triggered when a UIButton is clicked

```
@IBAction func shareButtonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    Flurry.logEvent("Share button tapped");


    let textToShare = quotetext.text 

    // 1.
    // Create and initialize a UIAlertController instance.
    //
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil,
                                            message: nil,
                                            preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    // 2.
    // Initialize the actions to show along with the alert.
    //
    let copyAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Copy Quote to clipboard",
                                   style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
                                    let pasteboard: UIPasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
                                    pasteboard.string = self.quotetext.text;
    }

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Share Quote",
                                      style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
                                        // We have contents so display the share sheet
                                        self.displayShareSheet(shareContent: textToShare)

    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        // ...
    }

    // 3.
    // Tell the alertController about the actions we want it
    // to present.
    //
    alertController.addAction(copyAction)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)


    // 4.
    // Present the alert controller and associated actions.
    //
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

This produces an alert that looks like

[image]

When 'Share Quote' is selected, the alert brings up a shareSheet.

This @IBAction works on iPhone, but is crashing on the iPad.  The error message is

> 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Your application has presented a
>   UIAlertController () of style
>   UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet. The modalPresentationStyle of a
>   UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You
>   must provide location information for this popover through the alert
>   controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a
>   sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is
>   not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in
>   the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method
>   -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'

I have tried to fix this problem by trying something like

```
    //iPad

    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = viewBottom
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = viewBottom.bounds
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.down;
```

This fix does not work.  The alert is positioned incorrectly over 'viewBottom' and when I click the 'defaultAction' button - it crashes again with the above error message.

I'm sort of at a loss here to fix this.  Can anyone give some advice on this?  I have tried various ways to use

> the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method
>   -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'

in my code, but wasn't successful.  Any advice appreciated on this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace these lines:

```
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = viewBottom
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = viewBottom.bounds
alertController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.down;
```

with:

```
if let button = sender as? UIButton {
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = button
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = button.bounds
}
```

You must also property setup the `popoverPresentationController` of the share sheet in your `displayShareSheet` method. You should probably pass in the `UIButton` as a parameter to that method so you can use it there.

Comment: Will you fix still work considering that my button is UIButton and not UIBarButtonItem?    I have an outlet already for it -- @IBOutlet weak var uploadBtn: UIButton!

Comment: Oops. I assumed it was a `UIBarButtonItem`. See my update for `UIButton`.

Comment: That worked great for the alertController!  It is positioned correctly.  The 'display sharesheet' is still crashing.  I'm not sure how I can configure the sharesheet in teh same way?

Comment: I already told you how in my answer. Pass the button to your `displayShareSheet` method and apply the same fix to the share sheet as you did to the alert.

Comment: Thank you!  Perfect

Comment: @rmaddy why are you setting both `sourceView` and `sourceRect`? Isn't one enough?

Comment: @kabiroberai You need both. Read the docs for the `sourceView` and `sourceRect` properties.

Comment: Huh. I thought that since `barButtonItem` did not require the other two, each one could function on its own. Although, I think that it would be more convenient if setting `sourceView` could set the `sourceRect` too.

Comment: @kabiroberai How? The view can be anything and the rect can be anywhere within the view. For `barButtonItem` it's easy to assume it should be displayed from anywhere around bar button item. But for an arbitrary `sourceView`, no assumption can be made about where within that view the popover should be displayed, hence the need for both `sourceView` and `sourceRect`.